# Using Apache camel read xml file and send it to rest service

Tags: apache-camel

Using camel how to read xml file from local directory and send that xml into restservice(mock service) which accepts any xml.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the following documentations:

- [File Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)
- [Camel Endpoints](http://camel.apache.org/components.html)
- [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html)

After that you know how to...:

1. ...read the file using the file component of apache camel.
2. If needed at all: ...process that xml file with xml slurper.
3. ..send the file to the rest service via the normal usage of the to()-method.

Maybe using camel as middleware to directly address that rest service is too much. Can't you forward that file directly, without a camel route?

Comment: I also find it very helpful to use read the examples on people.apache.org:
http://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/file2.html